# Check boxes alignment not working as expected

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, checkboxlist

I have few fields defined in my thymeleaf HTML template which are checkboxes and the code wrt them is like below. The values for the checkboxes are returned from the springboot controller

```html
<table>
<tr>
                <td>
                    Applicable on&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <span th:each="checkboxvalue : ${appOnValues}">
                                    <input type = "checkbox" th:field = "*{channel}" th:value = "${checkboxvalue}" />
                                    <label th:for = "${#ids.prev('channel')}" th:text = "${checkboxvalue}">
                                    </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </span>
                </td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Filter Level&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <span th:each="radiovalue : ${filterLevelValues}">
                                        <input type = "radio" th:field = "*{filterLevel}" th:value = "${radiovalue}" />
                                        <label th:for = "${#ids.prev('filterLevel')}" th:text = "${radiovalue}">
                                        </label>
                                    </span>
                </td>              
            </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the screenshot of the HTML file with the above code

[image: Checkboxes image]

Now I am trying to align the checkboxes horizontally but I am not able to do that. Here are the CSS files used within the HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/util.css" th:href="@{/css/util.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/css/tags.css" th:href="@{/css/tags.css}">
```

I am not sure whether it has to do with conflict because of any of the CSS files. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Can you set up fiddle with all code & css

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align: middle;` to `span` and `input` as shown below:

```css
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Applicable on&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span th:each="checkboxvalue : ${appOnValues}">
                                    <input type = "checkbox" th:field = "*{channel}" th:value = "${checkboxvalue}" />
                                    <label th:for = "${#ids.prev('channel')}" th:text = "${checkboxvalue}">
                                    </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Filter Level&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span th:each="radiovalue : ${filterLevelValues}">
                                        <input type = "radio" th:field = "*{filterLevel}" th:value = "${radiovalue}" />
                                        <label th:for = "${#ids.prev('filterLevel')}" th:text = "${radiovalue}">
                                        </label>
                                    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Alignment issue is fixed  but there is misalignment

Comment: remove margin:0; and check

Comment: Also some of my alignments are getting affected. I mean the border lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192941/discussion-between-aarish-ramesh-and-vikas-jadhav).

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this:

```css
input, label, td, span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
                <td>
                    Applicable on&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <span th:each="checkboxvalue : ${appOnValues}">
                                    <input type = "checkbox" th:field = "*{channel}" th:value = "${checkboxvalue}" />
                                    <label th:for = "${#ids.prev('channel')}" th:text = "${checkboxvalue}">
                                    </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </span>
                </td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Filter Level&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <span th:each="radiovalue : ${filterLevelValues}">
                                        <input type = "radio" th:field = "*{filterLevel}" th:value = "${radiovalue}" />
                                        <label th:for = "${#ids.prev('filterLevel')}" th:text = "${radiovalue}">
                                        </label>
                                    </span>
                </td>              
            </tr>
</table>
```